# DotNetZip - Create a Zip from a list of items

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, dotnetzip

I have an .NET C# application which request some information from database and store records in a list structure.

```
public Class Record {

   public string name { get; set; }
   public string surname { get; set; }
}

List<Record> lst = new List<Record>();
```

I would like to iterate over this list and adding each record to the zip file. I do not want to create a txt file containing all these records (a record by line) and then once file saved on disk, create the zip file from that file, I mean, I do not want to create an intermediate file on disk in order to create the zip file from that.

How can I do this using [DotNetZip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: It should work with any stream. Did you try a `MemoryStream`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ZipFile can take any stream.

```
ZipFile.AddEntry(string entryName, Stream stream)
```

You want to create a MemoryStream and then add that stream to the file.

For example:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream)) {
        foreach (var record in lst) {
            sw.WriteLine(record.surname + "," + record.name);
        }
        sw.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        using (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile()) {
            zipFile.AddEntry("Records.txt", stream);
            zipFile.Save("archive.zip");
        }
    }
}
```